# How to find File Size of each File present in Multiple Folders?

Tags: powershell, filesize

I have 1000+ Folders and each folder has an excel file. I want to find the file size of each excel file.Which Powershell commands to use for this. I am new to Powershell.

Comment: What you ask about is one of the most basic tasks in PowerShell. Therefore, I would recommend that you start with reading the documentation. PowerShell has some decent reference docs. What is more, there are some really great free and paid books about PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code would look through ALL folders in the parent folder (so recursively) and search for all files with a XLS or XLSX extention.
It would then grab the name and size:

```
gci -Path c:\myfolder -Recurse | where {$_.Extension -like '.xls*'} | 
Select FullName,  @{n='Size in KB';e={[int]($_.length / 1kb)}} -First 50
```

This stops after 50 documents. you can remove the -first 50 to search all files.

To be fair, it's these kind of exercises that will make you learn Powershell. You could have found this yourself with some dedication and patience. Not to be harsh or anything.

Comment: I would not post such examples. It looks like this is OP's homework task. Let him read the docs and learn PowerShell.

Comment: Yes, i just added that to my post. But fair enough. If they ask what the code does and how he came to it, it would be hard to explain tho.

Comment: Thank you guys ..Yes I have started reading books and online material. I just needed the direction on how to start. with the above answer I could now at least try to find the use of the commands . Thanks again

Comment: This is what I wrote taking your input and I got my result :)  .Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Userdata .\* -Include Report*.xls* -Recurse | Select Name,  @{n='Size in KB';e={[int]($_.length / 

1kb)}} | Export-Csv -Path D:\Result\result.csv

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the main command that you should use in this case is [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1) (aliased as `gci` or `dir`). Here is a simple example:

`Get-ChildItem -Path *.xlsx | Format-Table Length,Name`

This example will display a table that would include all files with *.xlsx in the current directory. You format the output with `Format-Table` cmdlet. You may also add `-Recurse` option to `gci` to make the command ehm recurse to child directories.

Answer (score 0):

Variation of Snakedoc solution (better in perf - work on PowerShell 3 minimum)

```
gci "C:\Temp" -file -filter "*.xls*" -Recurse |
    Select FullName,  @{n='Size';e={[int]($_.length / 1kb)}} -First 50
```